# Which input cable to use with a Dell WD15 dock when connecting a usb-c Macbook Pro

Tags: docking-stations

I'm using a Dell WD15 dock to connect my Dell Precision 5510 to an external monitor (HP Envy 27" 4k). This is a USB-C dock. The dock connects to the monitor using a HDMI cable. The display settings for the monitor are: 
resolution: 3840x2160, Scaling: 150%. The text on the monitor is very crisp.

Whereas if I connect my 13" 2017 Macbook Pro (usb-c), the text on the monitor is extremely blurry. the default display resolution is 2560x1440 at 60 Hz. I've even tried to use 4k resolution but the text isn't crisp. I also tried using the displayPort on the dock but to no avail.

This problem is eliminated when using a single usb-c cable and the text on the monitor becomes very crisp and clear at the default 2560x1440 resolution.

I would like to be able to use the dock with the Macbook Pro in order to take advantage of the various peripheral devices connected to the dock.

Comment: As a note of caution, the blurry text you describe does not sound like a hardware limitation. Have you tried Open System Preferences/Appearance -> Deselect/Select: Use LCD font smoothing when available.?

Comment: @Bennett Yeo I haven't tried that setting but I will and get back with the result.